# Johansen Cointgration test in python

Tags: python

Code:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm import coint_johansen
coint_johansen(df_t_1, 0, 1)
```

Output:

```
<statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.JohansenTestResult at 0x1dc52fcea00>
```

My data frame has two time series columns. I had 2 questions regarding the johansen cointegration test which I couldn't get answered on the [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.coint_johansen.html) or any other web-source:

1. Do I have to input the first-differenced data frame (which is stationary) or the original one (which is non-stationary)?
2. How do I get it to print the result? Enclosing with `print()` doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks :) 

The result is a class with multiple fields. These are documented [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.JohansenTestResult.html#statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.JohansenTestResult). 

For example, `result = coint_johansen(...)` and then `print(result.trace_stat)` should show some good result. Or `result.cvm`, etc. (I don't know about Johansen Cointegration, so I don't know which one you'd care about.)